# How to read data from two parent nodes in firebase in recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

How to read data from two different firebase database parent node in a recyclerview.
I want to fetch data from two different firebase parent node recyclerview, but i ended up reading only one node from firebase and displying to recycyclerview.

```
// Load data from Firebase into mDataList
private void loadDataFromFirebase() {

    mDataList.clear();
    mDatabase.child("QnA").child("Questions").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                scholarid = childSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
//                System.out.println(id);

                question_profile_read_data dataModel = childSnapshot.getValue(question_profile_read_data.class);
                mDataList.add(dataModel);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    System.out.println(scholarid);

    mDatabase.child("users").child("child").child("profiles").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                question_profile_read_data dataModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(question_profile_read_data.class);
                mDataList.add(dataModel);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                System.out.println(scholarid);
//            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

I used above method to retrieve data and i used this method in adapter class. but this only reading data from single database.

Comment: I think the `mDataList` value is getting updated based on the last call of `addValueEventListener`

Comment: but what to do to read at once both data in recyclerview....any idea ????

Comment: You can try declaring `dataModel` right below `mDataList.clear();`.  

Right now your `dataModel` is declared twice in both `addValueEventListener` which is leading to this issue. 
What you can try is declaring `question_profile_read_data dataModel` below `mDataList.clear();` and in `addValueEventListener` use `dataModel=childSnapshot.getValue(question_profile_read_data.class)`;

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and indicate the exact data you want to read.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work.